# android onLongClickListener undesirable behavior

Tags: java, android, behavior, onlongclicklistener

I'm using onLongClickListener and it's doing something unexpected. I've attached sample code for reference. I consumed the event so that no further action is taken. When the EditText is empty or you click in the whitespace, everything works as expected. When you click directly on any text in the EditText, a white "balloon" pops up with text included.

I have not been able to find a reference to this behavior or how to override it. Maybe I'm just not using the right keywords. Can anyone give me a nudge in the right direction?

From the xml:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
></EditText>
```

From the Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    edit.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);

}

OnLongClickListener longClickListener = new OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        doSomething();
        return true;
    }
};
```

EDIT: I'm using a Droid X as my test device running 2.2 if that makes any difference. Here's a screen shot. If I knew what this was called, I could find it and override it. Maybe I need to find the source code?

[image: Long Click]

Answer (score 0):

Calling setHapticFeedbackEnabled(false) for edit text should disable the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Already tried it. It turns off the vibrate feedback, but not the balloon popup. I reconfirmed it by using both the code and XML options to turn off haptic feedback. I'll try to get a screen shot to post.